# MediaCodec Async mode with NDK not triggering callback functions

Tags: android, h.264, android-mediacodec

I'm working on a demo to decode AVC stream using Android NDK MediaCodec. The following jni function is called from Kotlin, the MediaCodec callback functions, "notifyCallback", are not triggered. They don't work as expected.

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_initiald_avcdemo_MainActivityKt_configCodec(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz,
                                                     jobject surface, jobject frames) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Native_Gate", "configCodec>>>>");

    AMediaCodec* decoder = AMediaCodec_createCodecByName("OMX.google.h264.decoder");
    AMediaFormat* format = AMediaFormat_new();
    AMediaFormat_setString(format, "mime", "video/avc");
    AMediaFormat_setInt32(format, "width", 832);
    AMediaFormat_setInt32(format, "height", 480);

    ANativeWindow* window = ANativeWindow_fromSurface(env, surface);
    if(NULL == window){
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Native_Gate", "native window is null");
        return;
    }

    AMediaCodecOnAsyncNotifyCallback* notifyCallback = new  AMediaCodecOnAsyncNotifyCallback{
            []( AMediaCodec *codec,void *userdata,int32_t index)
            {
                __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Native_Gate", "onAsyncInputAvailable");
            },
            []( AMediaCodec *codec, void *userdata, int32_t index, AMediaCodecBufferInfo *bufferInfo)
            {
                __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Native_Gate", "onAsyncOutputAvailable");
            },
            [](AMediaCodec *codec, void *userdata, AMediaFormat *format)
            {
                __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Native_Gate", "onAsyncFormatChanged");
            },
            [](AMediaCodec *codec, void *userdata, media_status_t error,int32_t actionCode,
               const char *detail)
            {
                __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Native_Gate", "onAsyncError");
            }
    };


    media_status_t status = AMediaCodec_configure(decoder, format, window, NULL, 0);
    if(status != 0){
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Native_Gate", "config codec failed [%d]", status);
        return;
    }

    status = AMediaCodec_setAsyncNotifyCallback(decoder, *notifyCallback, nullptr);
    if(status != 0){
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Native_Gate", "set callback failed [%d]", status);
        return;
    }


    status = AMediaCodec_start(decoder);
    if(status != 0){
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Native_Gate", "start codec failed");
        return;
    }

 
    // ANativeWindow_release(window);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Native_Gate", "configCodec<<<<<");
}
```

Can anyone help me identify the root cause of this issue? or share me relvant documents.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec#setCallback(android.media.MediaCodec.Callback,%20android.os.Handler)):

> If the client intends to use the component in asynchronous mode, a
> valid callback should be provided before configure(MediaFormat,
> Surface, MediaCrypto, int) is called.

In your case, `AMediaCodec_setAsyncNotifyCallback` should be called before calling `AMediaCodec_configure`.